# Windows7 output batch file not to screen

Tags: windows, batch-file

I use a *.bat* file as a cron.

The *Windows task manager* calls this batch file every 5 minutes and this batchfile simply copies a few files.

The problem is that every 5 minutes a screen with the batch output is flash on the screen.
How can I prevent this batchfile shows the output on the screen?

```
@echo off
  copy C:\asb\APPL\BBX\WORK\pcadeau "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Dropbox\Bu_booking\" 
  copy C:\asb\APPL\BBX\WORK\pprosp "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Dropbox\Bu_booking\" 
  copy C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\4* "C:\asb\APPL\SYNC\bank.csv"
  move C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\4* "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Dropbox\Bu_booking\offline bank\bestanden\"
```

Comment: I've never managed it with a batch file. If your requirements are pretty static and you have C# coding experience you can do it with a C# program. Create a console application to do what you want then, to stop the window appearing, change the project Output Type to Windows Application. The console application still runs but produces no window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for this myself.
by simply add

```
>NUL
```

to the lines from wich you don't want output

In this example it's

```
copy C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\4* "C:\asb\APPL\SYNC\bank.csv" >NUL
copy C:\asb\APPL\BBX\WORK\pcadeau "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Dropbox\Bu_booking\"  >NUL
copy C:\asb\APPL\BBX\WORK\pprosp "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Dropbox\Bu_booking\" >NUL 
copy C:\Users\Gebruiker\Downloads\4* "C:\asb\APPL\SYNC\bank.csv"
```

Answer (score 3):

As all the resources being accessed are local, run the task under the credentials of the local system account. That way the task will run in another session and you will see nothing.

Answer (score 1):

When running a batch file as a task on my Win 7 PC I add a **/min** to the end of the **cmd.exe** line. This cases the command prompt to open then immediately minimises itself.